# How can create ApiKey for Authentication System in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to login my users from an Android phone and according to [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html#guard-auth-methods) article it is possible.

How can create a secure API key? Is there a special bundle for this?

Comment: First, answer yourself - how do you expect to be attacked with these apikeys?

Comment: In the future, please format your question correctly with spelling and grammar to help the readers.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [Jose library](https://github.com/namshi/jose) before, but I believe it's fallen out of maintenance. It looks like they recommend [Firebase JWT](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt). Which according to that page can be installed through Composer.